# if constexpr Seems to Only Work if Both Cases are Valid

Tags: c++, reflection, metaprogramming, compile-time, if-constexpr

Given the following code:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr remove_reference_t<decltype(T{}.x, bool{})> has_x() {return true;}
template<typename T, class... U>
constexpr bool has_x(U...) {return false;}

class A { public: int x; };

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    A my_a{};

    std::cout << has_x<decltype(my_a)>() << endl << has_x<decltype(vec)>() << endl;

    if constexpr(has_x<decltype(vec)>())
    {
        cout << vec.x << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << size(vec) << endl;
    }
}
```

It compiles only if I comment out the `cout << vec.x << endl`. This obviously won't compile, but my understanding from [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) was that:

> If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded

Thus I thought that "statement-true" should be discarded, but this doesn't seem to be the case. If I put a statement that's valid in either case in the "statement-true" it works. But with a potentially invalid statement I get:

> error: `class std::vector<int>` has no member named `x`

Am I doing something wrong here?

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fd4c93208bbbceb)

Comment: @SidS I don't understand, isn't `has_x<decltype(vec)>()` a valid condition?

Comment: `if constexpr` loses its magical power outside of templates (also the condition has to depend on a template parameter).

Comment: You cannot put invalid code inside a `if constexpr`, even in the "false" branch.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is almost true, but not quite. Discarding a substatement prevents it from odr-using the entities it references.

Comment: For example: https://godbolt.org/z/g6NQXV The condition cannot ever be true, but still trigger the error, even if not instanciated. GCC falsly accept this.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot If I remember correctly it's ill-formed NDR.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm pretty sure you are correct about that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a constexpr if, the body of the discarded statement must still be syntactically correct, even if it is not compiled.  The compiler knows at compile time that

```
vec.x
```

is incorrect, so you get an error.  If you refactor the code to use a template like

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& vec)
{
    if constexpr(has_x<T>())
    {
        cout << vec.x << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << size(vec) << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    A my_a{};

    std::cout << has_x<decltype(my_a)>() << endl << has_x<decltype(vec)>() << endl;
    foo(vec);

}
```

then

```
vec.x
```

is syntactically correct, it doesn't know what `vec` is, but it is not malformed code, so it passes.  Then, once the template is instantiated, the condition of the if statement is evaluated and the `vec.x` is discarded so there is no compiler error.

---

Typically you only use a constexpr if in template contexts.  You don't have to, but if you don't you have to make sure that the body will compile at compile time, even if it would be discarded, just like a plain old if statement.

---

Even inside templates you still have to be careful.  If the body of the constexpr if does not rely on the template parameter, then it will be evaluated before the template is ever instantiated.  Using

```
template <typename T>
void f() 
{
     if constexpr (std::is_integer_v<T>)
         // ...
     else
       static_assert(false, "T must be an integer type"); 
}
```

the code won't compile since `static_assert(false, "T must be an integer type")` triggers when the template is parsed.  You have to make the condition depend on the template type so it will be evaluated at instantiation time like

```
template<class T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
void f() 
{
     if constexpr (std::is_integer_v<T>)
         // ...
     else
       static_assert(always_false<T>, "T must be an integer type"); 
}
```